# Custom styling for Bootstrap select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I find the select Twitter Bootstrap's dropdown very ugly, how can I deactivate Bootstrap only for the select widget?
Or is it possible to customize the way the select dropdown looks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite the css styling by simply adding your own for example:

```
select {
   background: #333333;
}
```

This is a very basic example but its just an example of how you can customize it to your own liking.

Comment: It doesn't work. I think the dropdowns are too big so I styled it in my own css file with: select {width:50px;} Nonetheless, my css rule is not taken into account, it is the css inline rule generated by bootstrap that is taken into account...

Comment: added a class to the select so that my css now has priority

Answer (score 15):

Check it out:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

You can change the color of the dropdown button through the different classes.
And if you want another color, just override it in css. E.g.:

```
.btn {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: How do I change the border color of selectPicker through Javascript? please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38851856/how-to-change-border-color-of-bootstrap-select