# How to change border color of Bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, styling, bootstrap-select

For a custom framework like Bootstrap select https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ how do I change the border color of a select box in Javascript?

I tried this but does not work.

```
document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor = "red";
```

Javascript

```
function validate() {
    var ok = true;

    var box = document.getElementById("box").value;

    if (!box) {
        document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor = "red";
        ok = false;
    } 

    return ok;
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST">
    <select id="box" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option value="" selected="selected">select number</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: show your html related  code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the DOM element generated by `bootstrap-select`, it actually hides the original `select` element and creates its own structure with `div`,`span` and `buttons`. There isn't any official documentation provided to change its `border`, but as a workaround you could do it as below:

You need to change border of the `button` whose `class` is `btn dropdown-toggle btn-default`, which is generated by `bootstrap-select`. Since the element created will not be given any `id` we will make use of its `class` with `document.getElementsByClassName("classnames")[0]`

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn dropdown-toggle btn-default")[0].style.borderColor = "red";
```

---

**Update**

Explanation in comments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //add a change event to each selectpicker
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker().on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get current element's id
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); //get current element's selected value
    var condition = false; //default false to form valid
    $(this).selectpicker('setStyle', 'btn-danger', selected == "" ? "add" : "remove");
    if (id == "box") {//if its first select box
      condition = !(selected == 2 || selected == ""); //check if its value==2 or value=="" so that form validation depends of respective selects
      $("#box2").selectpicker(selected == 2 ? "show" : "hide").val("");
      //show or hide box2 based on selected val
      $("#box2").selectpicker('setStyle', 'btn-danger',"remove");
      //remove danger from 2nd selectpicker when its hidden or shown
    } else {
      condition = !(selected == "");
      //if its box 2 check if any value is selected
    }
    $(this).closest('form').data('valid', condition);
    //set it to form's data-valid attribute
  });
  $("#box2").selectpicker('hide');//default hide on page load
  
  //form submit event instead of validate() inline function
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//prevent default action of submit
    var isValid = $(this).data('valid');//check if its valid
    if (!isValid) {
      //if not valid loop through each selectpicker
      $.each($('.selectpicker'),function(){
        var selected=$(this).val();
        //check appropriate values for each select and set/remove the btn-danger class for respective selectpickers
        $(this).selectpicker('setStyle', 'btn-danger', selected == "" ? "add" : "remove"); 
      })
    }
    else{
      alert(isValid);
      //Submit your form
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!--add data-valid attribute to form to make sure its valid or not and default to false-->

<form action="#" data-valid="false" method="POST">
  <select id="box" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">select number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="box2" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">select number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But this will change the border color of all bootstrap dropdown buttons?

Comment: I know you used a [0] there but how does the browser know which is the [0]th button

Comment: so I am basically trying to do form validation. If this select is empty I the border to show up red

Comment: That's why I have to do it in JS

Comment: @jebmarcus Any issues?

Comment: I fixed this issue by doing document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group")[0].style.border = '1px solid red';

Comment: @jebmarcus.. With regarding to the problem you are finding in targeting specific `select` elements, you could just look into how to select particular element under another element in javascript to maintain uniqueness.. Happy coding..

Comment: what really confuses me is if you look at this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5827v34j/), this functionality works. And my code on my local machine is exactly the same but does not work

Comment: place a debugger and see what's happening? I hope you understand how to place a debugger in javascript and debug web application..

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io//css/highlight.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io//css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io//css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://silviomoreto.github.io//dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select id="box" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="warning">

                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select number</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="button" style="width: 180px; height: 30px" onclick="changeColor()" value="Validate"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        function changeColor() {
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderWidth = "1px";
            return false;
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can override the CSS

> .bootstrap-select{   border: 1px solid red  //sample }

Hope this helps

Update:
By using JavaScript, this can be done as shown below (considering all required JS file as added already)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select id="box" name="num" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="warning">

                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select number</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="button" style="width: 10px; height: 30px" onclick="changeColor()" value="Validate"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        function changeColor() {
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderWidth = "1px";
            return false;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: I need to change it in Javascript not css

Comment: @jebmarcus Gaurav has good idea too.. You don't need `javascript` if you use `CSS` as this will be applied at any cost. But you need to specify proper class as in `.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-default` instead of `.bootstrap-select`.. +1 for the idea..

Comment: @Gaurav P I must do this in JS because I need to do form validation. Please see updated question

Comment: @jebmarcus: Check my updated answer, this will work. Please close if you find solution.

Comment: @GauravP this doesn't work. How is it different from what I had originally?

Comment: You have to add document.getElementById("box").style.borderWidth = "1px";
This is working on IE and Firefox, I had not tested on others

Comment: @GauravP how did this work for you, didn't work for me and I tested it in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @jebmarcus: Check Snippet which I had added

Comment: im going to put your code into a JSfiddle and see how it works, for some reason it still doesnt work for me

Comment: @GauravP please take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/je4p2L4b/ I tried adding a borderWidth like you did in your function, but does not work

Comment: @jebmarcus: Check your html markups enclosing
https://jsfiddle.net/5827v34j/ This is working

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```css
    .form-select:focus{
        outline: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        border: 1px solid #008080;
    }
```