# How can I change the border color on my <select> element without effecting bootstrap css styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap (v4.5.3) form, where my selects look like this in firefox:

[image: Select Options]

When someone tries to submit the form, I have some JS code that runs, and does validation. One of the things it checks for is that someone actually chose an option, and didn't leave it on `-- Select an Option --`. When I detect this, my javascript would stop form submission, and highlight the option by setting the border to red:

```
ELEMENT.style.borderColor = "red";
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, my select loses whatever styling bootstrap put on it, and looks like this:

[image: Invalid Select]

I left the bottom one untouched for easy comparison.

Am I highlighting it wrong? Is there some css class I'm supposed to use instead of changing the borderColor?

Edit: See https://jsfiddle.net/xbqucoLp/ for example

Comment: Can you create and share a minimal code sandbox?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid Not a web developer, so I've never used one of those before, though I've seen them around. I can give it a try when I have a few minutes.

Comment: Try adding this in your script in the meantime. ELEMENT.style.borderWidth = "1px";

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid the width of the red border definitely changes, but the bootstrap styling still goes away

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38851856/how-to-change-border-color-of-bootstrap-select

Comment: @AshRingler that question appears to do with [bootstrap-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-select). Is that different from the regular bootstrap I'm using? Some sort of special plugin for `select` handling? Or are they talking about just regular bootstrap?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid Added link to jsfiddle. Surprisingly easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap actually comes with validation CSS built in. The style of the select in bootstrap is different to what you have in your question so it may not be to your liking. It does however keep the select arrow consistent unlike what you currently have.
See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/ for details

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gqL7641/1/

The advantage of using this is that when you choose an option it changes from red to green.

If the above is unacceptable to you, then the following will work:

You can use outline instead of border and this doesn't change the styling of select

```
this.style.outline = "solid 1px red";
```

Another way of changing the outline without touching border is to use shadow

```
.redOutline {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(255,0,0,0.5); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

and use the following to add the outline

```
this.classList.add("redOutline");
```

You can tweak the shadow CSS using this tool https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/

Comment: I was pretty sure bootstrap had this, but couldn't find it for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a class to the element instead?

like this

```
element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

that might work as long as the only thing that class contains is a border color with !important

Answer (score 0):

Ah I didn't realize there was a difference sorry. Usually for these custom selects, there are classes that overlay the browser select to get custom features. I would see if you can target those classes and change their border color. Looking for the elements in the browser dev-tools allows you to change their css in the browser to test if you can do that to see what element you need to target.

Comment: Not sure where these classes are. Like I said - I'm not a web developer, so I might be missing something, but I can't see them in firefox's dev tools. I selected the `select` element, and unchecked every single CSS property on it, and the arrows on the `select` are still the fancy bootstrap arrows. Not sure how it sets those, or why setting a border color removes them. Setting an inline property in firefox's dev tools on `select` to change the border color does the same thing as I'm seeing - removes the fancy bootstrap formatting. Can't figure out why.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29513693/1011984 recommends getting rid of Firefox's own chrome so your styling (or Bootstrap's) can be what is seen.

Comment: @RichDeBourke Using the class in that post, it does indeed get rid of the fancy styling, but bootstrap doesn't replace this with its own, so it just remains super basic.