# How to change background-color option in bootstrap-select?

Tags: css, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap-select (from Silvio Moreto). I would like to change background-color and font color of list item. By default is :

[image]

And I would like something like :

[image]

I tried this, but nothing change :

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li:hover{
      background-color: rgb(191, 82, 121);
      color: white;
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304430/custom-styling-for-bootstrap-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304430/custom-styling-for-bootstrap-select)

Comment: Because I'm using bootstrap-select library your trick doesn't work, but it could be very interesting another time !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I answered my own question :

```
 .bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
     color: whitesmoke !important;
     background: #bf5279 !important;
 }
```

Thanks ;-) !

Comment: I had mistakenly searched bootstrap-select but instead wanted ajax-autocomplete. If anyone is interested for ajax-autocomplete it is `.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover`

Answer (score 2):

I have changed all of them with something like this:

```
button[data-toggle="dropdown"].btn-default,
button[data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
background-color: white !important;
color: #2c3e50 !important;
border: 2px solid #dce4ec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a demo or live-site my only guesses would be to either use "!important" on background-color or check if your css selector ist right. What happens, if you change outline or border? If nothings happens, i would think, that your selector is wrong or your css isn´t even included.

Comment: You're right, my selector was wrong, I needed to get also <a> after <li>